When does positive skew imply median<mean?
For a random variable $X$, the skew is defined as $S(X):={\frac {E\overline{X}^3}{(E\overline{X}^2)^{3/2}}}$, where $\overline{X}=X-EX$. It is often claimed that positive (resp. negative) skew implies that the mean of $X$ is larger (resp. smaller) than the median of $X$.
However this implication can fail. For example, on a mixture of two Gaussians with appropriate chosen parameters (this can be checked directly). But it can even fail on unimodal distributions, for example the Weibull distribution (cf. Groeneveld, Skewness for the Weibull Family, 1986).
What additional conditions can we place on $X$ that will ensure $sign(Skew(X))=sign(mean(X)-median(X))$? Clearly there are trivial answers such as stipulating that $X$ belongs to a certain family of distributions, but I am wondering if there is any more general or nice condition.

Some similar Qs Why is the arithmetic mean > median on a histogram skewed to the right?, Empirical relationship between mean, median and mode,

The comment by @stats has considerable force. No answer will be satisfactory, because you can change $X$ in arbitrarily tiny ways while effecting arbitrarily large and different changes in the skewness and mean.  (Merely contaminate $X$ with a suitable atomic distribution.) Thus, trivial results can be asserted: e.g., people can reference families of distributions where this equivalent always holds, but that's of little or no interest because it's just a property of the family and not of random variables generally.

@whuber, I'm not sure I understand your objection. Ultimately there's some set S of distributions with the desired property, and I'm asking for a sufficient condition on $X$ that ensures $X\in S$. The fact that you can perturb a distribution in S to bump it out of S or vice versa doesn't imply that there can't be an interesting answer to that question (besides I'm not sure I would consider the changes you describe as "arbitrarily tiny", but that is beside the point).

My point is that it's unlikely you will find anything other than a direct restatement of the original condition.

@Matt Geometrically, this question is the same as (say) describing a region $R$ in the plane with a simple formula and asking for other formulas that would describe that region, too. The "plane" is really the space of all distributions with a natural topology (such as convergence in distribution). Literally any answer will be of the form "well, if you restrict to such-and-such a subset of the plane [that is, a specified family of distributions], then here's a different-looking characterization of its intersection with $R$." I find that too broad and vague to be suitable here.

@whuber I really find this characterization quite unfair and dismissive. Insofar as modern probability theory is based on the language of mathematics which is itself based on the language of set theory, basically any question one could possibly ask would ultimately come down to "describing some region (set)".  Clearly some descriptions are more nice or probabilistically meaningful than others- the criteria for what makes a description nice are admittedly sociological, but I don't think that makes the question ill-posed.

I don't see why you think @whuber's characterization is either unfair or dismissive. He's basically saying that he doesn't believe there's going to be a meaningful answer—one other than what you've already classified as "trivial," and he outlines his reasons why. He's not the only one—I doubt it, too, and statsplease below apparently does as well.

@MattF. - yep!  And I upvoted it too!

The statement that the mean is greater than the median is simply a statement of
$$F_{X}(\mathbb{E}[X])>0.5$$
for a random variable $X$ with distribution function $F_{X}(x)$.
This has nothing (directly) to do with skewness.
To impose a direct relationship between this statement and skewness (being positive) would just result in some inequality like
$$\mathbb{E}\bigg[\bigg(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\bigg)^{3}\bigg]>0\quad\Rightarrow\quad \mathbb{E}[X^3]>\mathbb{E}[X](3σ^2+\mathbb{E}[X]^2)$$
where $\mathbb{E}[X]>F^{-1}_X(0.5)$ and $σ^2$ is taken to be finite.
Any distribution satisfying this inequality is what you're after.

Thanks, but I can't consider this a satisfying answer as it is basically just a restatement of my question. Yes, I'm after the distributions for which $F_X(\mu)>.5 \Leftrightarrow EX^3>\mu(3\sigma^2+\mu^2)$--but which distributions satisfy this? Is there a simple sufficient condition I can check in practice?

You asked under what conditions on $X$ can we conclude that positive skewness implies mean greater than median. That's what was answered.

The sort of answer I had in mind is one that introduces an additional property of X that is easier to verify than directly computing the skew, mean, and median, like "if X is unimodal and not heavy tailed, then Skew and mean-median have the same sign". I don't know whether this particular claim is true, it is just an example of what I would consider a satisfying answer.

I'm not sure the condition you're after exists. We can stipulate conditions like "no unimodal, continuous, symmetric distributions" (because naturally mean equals median) but the general condition you're after is the one already stated in the answer. We can pick specific families of distributions like Weibull and say any $X\sim\text{Weibull}(\lambda,k<3.439541\ldots)$. But once again that is just a specific application of the general condition above.

To be clear, I am not asking about an if-and-only-if condition, but just an if-condition: that is, some clause $Q(X)$ such that $Q(X)\Rightarrow sign(Skew(X))=sign(Mean(X)-Median(X))$. It's true of course that for any logical implication of the form $Q\Rightarrow P$ that $Q$ will be a "specific application" of $P$ but my question is whether there is some $Q$ that is easier to check in practice or more statistically meaningful than $P$ itself. I agree that an interesting if-and-only-if condition is unlikely to exist.

Hopefully I'm not misunderstanding you. The if-condition(s) you seek would be extremely specific to the family the distribution belonged to. This is because all the things involved in $Q$ are specific to a family. I gave you an example in a previous comment. If $X\sim\text{Weibull}(\lambda, k<3.439541)$. This is an if-condition that satisfies but only for a specific family of distributions.

Sure, the Weibull example would be an if-condition and would technically be an answer to my question; it sounds like you agree that would not be a satisfying answer. I just don't see why Q would have to reference a specific family. I similarly gave you an example in a previous comment, Q could be something like "X is unimodal and not heavy-tailed." Again I don't know whether this condition would actually imply the property, but it doesn't seem obvious to me that no condition like this could possibly imply it either.

@SimonSegert Consider this simplified framing. Imagine there are only two distributions in the universe of distributions that exists, Weibull and Gamma. This is obviously a framing that is infinitely simpler than your question. All Gamma distributions satisfy positive skewness with mean greater than median. We already addressed the Weibull case. What possible meaningful condition can you construct for just these two cases that characterizes them in a general way?

@MattF. I think it's very meaningful and interesting. But it invokes a specification of a (albeit broad) family of distributions (if I haven't interpreted it incorrectly). Was the OP asking for that not to be the case? Perhaps the question has changed, which is obviously fine.

Here are some results I found in the literature. I'll assume without loss of generality that $EX=0$ and $EX^2=1$ (in particular, $Skew(X)=EX^3$). I'll also assume that $X$ has a density function $p$.

If $p(x)-p(-x)$ changes sign exactly once in $x$, then $$Skew>0 \iff Mean>Median$$ [Mac]. This includes all distributions from the Pearson family as well as lognormal and inverse Gaussian.

If $X_1, X_2, \dots$ are independent copies of $X$ and $S_n$ is the sum of the first $n$ copies, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}
Median(S_n) = \frac{-1}{6}Skew(X)$$ This has certain technical assumptions which are not too stringent and can be founded in the referenced paper. (Due to [Hall], with an earlier version proved by [Hald]). Since $$Skew(S_n)>0 \iff Skew(X)>0$$
we thus expect
$$Skew(S_n)>0 \iff Median(S_n)<0$$
for sufficiently large n.


The paper actually proves a stronger statement: namely that the median goes as $-{\frac 1 6}skew+{\frac C n}$, to leading order in $n$. Here $C$ is a certain explicit expression that involves the first five moments of $X$. This allows us to estimate a finite $n$ value for which the skew-median relation will hold. Namely, it holds for $S_n$ provided that $-{\frac 1 6}|skew|+{\frac {sign(skew)C} n}<0$.
[Hall] P. Hall, On the Limiting Behaviour of the Mode and Median of a Sum of Independent Random Variables, Annals of Probability, 1980,
[Hald] J Haldane,The mode and median of nearly normal distribution with given cumulants, Biometrika, 1942.
[Mac] H MacGillivray, The mean, median, and mode inequality and skewness for a class of densities, Australian Journal of Statistics, 1982.

#2 isn't really helpful w.r.t. your OP, as it's a characterization of the limiting behavior, not of an actual distribution.   Also, providing a reference to a paywalled article, as you have with your reference for #1, is less helpful than you might think.

@jbowman you are correct that the result in 2 is asymptotic, thank you for the correction. The paper actually proves a stronger result which allows us to estimate the minimal value of n (and thus an actual distribution) for which the relation will hold; I've edited the answer to include this result as well. With regard to paywalled articles this is sadly a fact of life and I would be happy to hear any suggestion for better ways to refer to results that are proved in such articles.

@Matt F. Surprisingly (at least to me), there is no division by n in that result.

Much better, thanks for modifying the answer to get rid of the purely asymptotic nature of #2.  I'd say that, if the technical assumptions aren't too lengthy (whatever that means) entering them in text would be good, otherwise, as you say, paywalls are a fact of life.

@Matt F. - I looked into this. The main technical condition in the Hall paper (which I omitted from the answer) is a certain bound on the characteristic function of X. According to Wikipedia, there is no known simple expression for the CF when X is lognormal, so  unfortunately it doesn't seem like there would be an easy way to verify this condition holds.
